# Encryption key generation and app performance

Tags: encryption, aes

A question for cryptography experts. Imagine we have a conceptual **Notes.app**:

- There are notes (title|content) stored as AES-256 encrypted strings
- Application has to present a list of all notes (titles) in a list on its main window
- Every title|content is encrypted with a key, generated from a password and a salt
- Let's imagine the key generation algorithm takes ~80ms on a mobile device to generate a key

With the following conditions, it would take almost **1 second** to decrypt 10 note titles. But what if there are lots of notes?

My 2 pennies on the problem: Encrypt all notes with different initialization vectors, but also with identical salt. That would allow me to generate a decryption key only once and decrypt lots of notes fast.

The question: doing so we would end up with lots of different notes, encrypted with an identical key. Does that somehow compromise the security of AES encryption? Is it possible that knowing there's a bunch of files with not just identical password, but also identical salt somehow makes it possible to crack the encryption?

Thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AES-256** do not use a salt. But I guess you use the salt together with the password in a PBE algorithm to generate the key. Usually this kind of PBE algorithms are constructed to be computational expensive - thus the 80 ms you see on your mobile.

When encrypting different messages, you could instead of using different salts to create different keys, just use different **initialization vectors (IV)** but the same key. The different **IV** ensures that messages that starts with the same block encrypts to different messages.

Comment: Ebbe, thanks for your answer! But i just want to clarify one thing: if i have N files, encrypted with the same key, but different IVs - does it help a hacker somehow, other than saying "all of these files have the same password"? Or does IV ensure that there are no statistical weaknesses that could be exploited? I really don't care if someone finds out that a bunch of files have the same key if they can't somehow compare those files to determine the password easier.

Comment: It's OK to use the same key for encrypting several times. However,  without a IV, the same clear data would always give the same encrypted data - the IV counter that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's basically what i wanted to know.